# Grabbing the value of "@type" from application/ld+Json script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a variable in GTM which would return just the value "product" from the following schema:

```
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org/",
    "@type":"Product","name":"Pendentif Girafe Rond 16 mm, Finition argentée","description":"Un joli bijou, pour briller de jour comme de nuit. Votre pendentif serti d'oxydes de zirconium se personnalise en ajoutant un cuir de couleur réversible et une chaîne (vendus séparément).",
    "mpn":"70318721608000",
    "sku":"70318721608000",
    "image":[null,null,null],
    "offers":{
        "url":{},
        "@type":"Offer",
        "priceCurrency":"EUR",
        "price":"39.00",
        "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is GTM? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Google Tag Manager

Comment: I just want a javascript funtion to return the value "Product"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Google Tag Manager, but you can parse the JSON data like this:

```js
const jsonData = JSON.parse( document.getElementById("json-data").innerText );

console.log(jsonData["@type"]);
```

```html
<script id="json-data" type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Pendentif Girafe Rond 16 mm, Finition argentée",
  "description": "Un joli bijou, pour briller de jour comme de nuit. Votre pendentif serti d'oxydes de zirconium se personnalise en ajoutant un cuir de couleur réversible et une chaîne (vendus séparément).",
  "mpn": "70318721608000",
  "sku": "70318721608000",
  "image": [
    null,
    null,
    null
  ],
  "offers": {
    "url": {},
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "price": "39.00",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: to be clear, you can access an object property either by the dot notation `obj.property` OR with square brackets `obj["property"]` ; the later makes it possible to use a property name with illegal characters (when using dot notation)